# Mongodb returning unrecognized "DocumentQuery" type with Typescript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, visual-studio-code

```
update(Id: number, updates: IDocument) {
    return Collection.findOneAndUpdate({ Id: Id }, updates, { new: true, upsert: true })
}
```

When running this code, the update method returns type:

```
DocumentQuery<IDocumentModel, IDocumentModel>
```

However, typescript does not recognize DocumentQuery so i have to use "any" as the type returned.

Do I have to stick to using "any" or is there a type that matches the return value more specifically?

FYI:

-I have both mongodb and mongoose types installed.

-I am using visual studio code.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, if you want to combine the typescript with mongoose, you can use async/await to avoid this type issue.

So basically, you can add exec() at the very end or give a callback function to the findOneAndUpdate. Instead of DocumentQuery, try to let it return a promise.